# Is there an autoclean option available on tomcat containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, storage, amazon-ecs

We have faced an issue from UAT environment where when user uploads a file from application(running on ECS fargate with just ephemeral storage), it results in No Space left on Device.
Rebooting the application clean-up temporary directory space(/usr/local/tomcat/temp).

I am seeking a possibility of autocleanup option in Tomcat(if any), so that there is cyclic cleanup process and we don't get these issues again.

we will look into other options like having a scalable storage for temporary directory in case we don't find any solution.

Comment: You probably need to update your Java code to delete the temporary file once it is finished processing it.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat per se would not clog up your disk (unless you forget to configure log rotation), so the accumulation of files comes from some application. That's where a cleanup would also have to come from somewhere else than Tomcat. Most likely the application that creates or that consumes the files should perform the cleanup.

If all else breaks, you could also add cron jobs to remove files.